# Is a date (m/y) after or equal to another

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to work out if a date is after or the same as another date. But only looking at the month/year, i need to exclude the day from the comparison.

```
$paymentDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2014-05-04");
$expiryDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/y", "03/17");

if ($paymentDate->format('m/y') >= $expiryDate->format('m/y')) {

   echo "Payment date is after or equal to the expiry date - payment won't work";

}
```

Why is this echoing the statement? Am I comparing this wrong? I thought you could compare dates this way.

Comment: Compare the YEAR first, __then__ the MONTH: `if ($paymentDate->format('ym') >= $expiryDate->format('ym')) {` otherwise `12/2014` comes after `01/2015`;

Comment: Assuming your dates come from a database ? do it in query if they are

Comment: @MarkBaker yes that worked. Is it always best to use the US style date format then for this reason?

Comment: That isn't US date format, US date format is `m/d/Y`.... generally speaking, look at how your database "displays" dates by default (`Y-m-d H:i:s`) which makes for easy comparisons as a formatted string

Comment: use strtotime and check what formats it actually accepts..perhaps you don't even need to format the string: https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @MarkBaker oh of course, but it's always best to compare with the year first then for this type of comparison?

Comment: For this type of comparison, it's absolutely essential to handle the comparison in that order. If you were simply comparing DateTimes, then you don't need to use any formatting; the instance you narrow down that comparison, the easiest is to compare formatted strings in the way I showed, and using year, then month, then day, then hour, etc to the level of detail you need

Comment: Is there a way to modify the date time objects in that case to just describe a month and year?

Comment: No it isn't while still retaining the actual date, but it's easy to do the formatted comparison in the way I showed.... If you don't mind losing the actual date, then set each datetime object to the 1st of the month at 00:00:00, then you can simply compare the objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by Mark Baker in the comments below the question.

Compare the YEAR first, then the MONTH:

```
if ($paymentDate->format('ym') >= $expiryDate->format('ym')) {}
```

otherwise 12/2014 comes after 01/2015;

Answer (score -1):

try

```
if (strtotime($paymentDate->format('m/y')) >= strtotime($expiryDate->format('m/y'))){}
```